# gitignore not working (".foo" pattern doesn't match "test.foo" filename)

Tags: git, github

I have a .gitignore file in a directory (not root)

```
.ascii
```

but these files keep appearing as untracked when I was about to commit the changes.

```
Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   new file:   test.ascii
```

I'm sure that these files are in the same dir as the ignore file.
Why are the rules in ignore file not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ascii` does't match `test.ascii`. You want to precede the extension with a wildcard: `*.ascii`.